# How to manually setup Whonix networks for QEMU?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, bridge, ethernet

I would like to run Whonix directly using QEMU instead of using libvirt and I want to manually setup internal and external network. Using libvirt I would need to run those commands:

```
virsh net-define Whonix-External.xml
virsh net-define Whonix-Internal.xml
virsh net-start Whonix-External.xml
virsh net-start Whonix-Internal.xml
```

Whonix-External.xml:

```
<network>
  <name>Whonix-External</name>
  <forward mode='nat'/>
  <bridge name='virbr1' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <ip address='10.0.2.2' netmask='255.255.255.0'/>
</network>
```

Whonix-Internal.xml:

```
<network>
  <name>Whonix-Internal</name>
  <bridge name='virbr2' stp='on' delay='0'/>
</network>
```

I only know that I have to use `ip link` and `ip tuntap` commands for that but I'm not even sure where to start, especially that Whonix-Gateway uses both networks and both Whonix-Gateway and Whonix-Workstation share Whonix-Internal network. I also know I will have to add `-netdev` and `-device` options to the QEMU command but I don't know how to make the VM pick the right network e.g. how to tell Whonix-Workstation to use Whonix-Internal instead of Whonix-External. If there are any other informations needed let me know and I will edit the post if needed.

## Solution

After a month of searching for a solution I found a way to set up both networks and I decided to share it here.

Firstly I created bridge called `virbr1` and tap device called `vnet0` which is Whonix-External network for Whonix-Gateway:

### virbr1

```
ip link add virbr1 type bridge
ip link set virbr1 type bridge stp_state 1
ip link set virbr1 up
```

### vnet0

```
ip tuntap add dev vnet0 mode tap user $(whoami)
ip link set vnet0 master virbr1
ip link set vnet0 up
```

Secondly I created bridge called `virbr2` and tap device called `vnet1` which is Whonix-Internal network for Whonix-Gateway:

### virbr2

```
ip link add virbr2 type bridge
ip link set virbr2 type bridge stp_state 1
ip link set virbr2 up
```

### vnet1

```
ip tuntap add dev vnet1 mode tap user $(whoami)
ip link set vnet1 master virbr2
ip link set vnet1 up
```

Thirdly I created tap device called `vnet2` which would be used by Whonix-Workstation to connect to Whonix-Internal network:

### vnet2

```
ip tuntap add dev vnet2 mode tap user $(whoami)
ip link set vnet2 master virbr2
ip link set vnet2 up
```

Lastly I added `iptables` rules (which I decided to put into separate chains so it will be easier to clean things up later) and enabled IP forwarding:

```
iptables -N WHONIX_FORWARD
iptables -A WHONIX_FORWARD -s 10.0.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT -i virbr1
iptables -A WHONIX_FORWARD -d 10.0.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT -o virbr1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A FORWARD -j WHONIX_FORWARD
iptables -t nat -N WHONIX_POSTROUTING
iptables -t nat -A WHONIX_POSTROUTING -s 10.0.2.0/24 ! -d 10.0.2.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j WHONIX_POSTROUTING
sysctl -wq net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

To make it all work I had to add these options to Whonix-Gateway's QEMU command:

```
-device virtio-net-pci,id=net0,netdev=hostnet0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5,mac=MAC
-netdev tap,id=hostnet0,ifname=vnet0,script=no,downscript=no
-device virtio-net-pci,id=net1,netdev=hostnet1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6,mac=MAC
-netdev tap,id=hostnet1,ifname=vnet1,script=no,downscript=no
```

and I had to add those options to Whonix-Workstation's QEMU command:

```
-device virtio-net-pci,id=net0,netdev=hostnet0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5,mac=MAC
-netdev tap,id=hostnet0,ifname=vnet2,script=no,downscript=no
```

After virtual machines will shut down I can clean everything up with those commands:

```
ip link del virbr1
ip tuntap del dev vnet0 mode tap
ip tuntap del dev vnet1 mode tap
ip link del virbr2
ip tuntap del dev vnet2 mode tap

iptables -D FORWARD -j WHONIX_FORWARD
iptables -F WHONIX_FORWARD
iptables -X WHONIX_FORWARD
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -j WHONIX_POSTROUTING
iptables -t nat -F WHONIX_POSTROUTING
iptables -t nat -X WHONIX_POSTROUTING
sysctl -wq net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
```

Comment: Don't run using qemu directly instead of libvirt. That way lies madness.

Comment: @MichaelHampton unfortunately I have to because I have two problems related to libvirt. First of them is that performance was really bad no matter how much memory I gave to the VM (I have 16 GBs so that should be more than enough). Second problem is that I want to run the VM using the script so I can hide it on hidden volume. With libvirt there would be much logs and other things proving that I was running Whonix even if nobody will be able to find Whonix files.